# LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'image' has not been initialized.)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making an application to hide messages in pictures,
everything is running smoothly and i have declared everything, but there is a problem i'm having "LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'image' has not been initialized.)". can anyone help me?

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hideimage/action/decode_req.dart';
import 'package:hideimage/action/encode_req.dart';
import 'package:hideimage/fight/decode.dart';
import 'package:hideimage/fight/encode.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
final picker = ImagePicker();
late Uint8List image;
String text = "Example";
bool isLoading = false;

Future getImage() async {
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
if (pickedFile != null) {
  setState(() {
    isLoading = true;
  });
  File _image = File(pickedFile.path);
  EncodeRequest request =
      EncodeRequest(_image.readAsBytesSync(), "", key: "");

  image = await encodeMessageIntoImageAsync(request);
  setState(() {
    isLoading = false;
  });
} else {
  print('No Image Selected');
}


 }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(text),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: isLoading 
          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
          : image != null
          ?  Text('No Image Selected')
          : GestureDetector(
            child: Image.memory(image),
            onTap: () async {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = true;
              });
              DecodeRequest request = DecodeRequest(image, key: "");
              text = await decodeMessageFromImageAsync(request);
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
            },
          )
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: getImage,
        tooltip: 'Pick Image',
        child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ),
    );
   }
  }
```

Comment: The [tag:c++] tag is irrelevant here. I don't see any C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

you have a misunderstanding, `late` variables are not nullable, you are only telling the compiler that you will assign its value later but still before using it.

here you are checking if `image != null` so image has not been initialized yet, thus you get this error.

what you need here is making `image` nullable not late
i.e change the declaration to this

```
Uint8List? image;
```

Comment: I've tried it, but there is an error in this section  `child: Image.memory(image)`

Comment: `@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return Scaffold( appBar: AppBar( title: Text(text), ), body: Center( child: isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : image != null ? Text('No Image Selected') : GestureDetector( child: Image.memory(image), onTap: () async { setState(() { isLoading = true; }); DecodeRequest request = DecodeRequest(image, key: ""); text = await decodeMessageFromImageAsync(request); setState(() { isLoading = false; }); }, ) ), floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton( onPressed: getImage, tooltip: 'Pick Image', child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo), ), ); } }`

Comment: cause you reversed the condition, you check if the `image` is not null then display a text if its null then show the image, which is null, thats why it throws an error. change the condition to be `image == null` instead of `!=`

Comment: thank you this is going well, but how do I call `image` section `child: Image.memory(image)`?

Comment: it will get called when the image is not null, try adding an image and it will work